# Analysis of Log with Spark Streaming

Tags: hdfs, spark-streaming, flume

I recently did analysis on a static log file with Spark SQL (find out stuff like the ip addresses which appear more than ten times). The problem was [from this site](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/logs_analyzer/chapter1/spark.html). But I used my own implementation for it. I read the log into an RDD, turned that RDD to a DataFrame (with the help of a POJO) and used DataFrame operations.

Now I'm supposed to do a similar analysis using Spark Streaming for a streaming log file for a window of 30 mins as well as aggregated results for a day. The solution can again be found [here](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/logs_analyzer/chapter1/total.html) but I want to do it another way. So what I've done is this

- Use Flume to write data from the log file to an HDFS directory
- Use JavaDStream to  read the .txt files from HDFS

Then I can't figure out how to proceed. Here's the code I use

```
Long slide = 10000L; //new batch every 10 seconds
Long window = 1800000L; //30 mins
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("StreamLogAnalyzer");
JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(slide));
JavaDStream<String> dStream = streamingContext.textFileStream(hdfsPath).window(new Duration(window), new Duration(slide));
```

Now I can't seem to decide if I should turn each batch to a DataFrame and do what I previously did with the static log file. Or is this way time consuming and overkill.

I'm an absolute noob to Streaming as well as Flume. Could someone please guide me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DataFrame (and Dataset) in Spark is most promoted way in latest versions of Spark, so it's a right choice to go with. I think that some obscurity appears because of non-explicit nature of stream, when you move files into HDFS rather than read from any event log.

Main point here is to choose correct batch time size (or slide size as in your snippet), so application would process data it loaded under that time slot and there would not be batch queue.